# How to properly parse a JSON file to use it through the JQuery Ajax method?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, parsing, getjson

I created the following **JSON array**:

```
[
  {
    "nome": "Aldo Maria",
    "indirizzo": "Viale Europa 1",
    "telefono": "3397889034"
  },
  {
    "nome": "Maria13",
    "indirizzo": "Viale Europa 1",
    "telefono": "3397889034"
  }
]
```

and I have a Javascript file in which I want to **cycle the two elements** of this array.
I want to do that by using the **Jquery ajax method** explained [here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/).

In other terms, I supposed I should use the following sintax:

> $(selector).getJSON(url,data,success(data,status,xhr))

I'm trying to apply that and wrote the following snippet into my javascrpt file, where I want to cycle the elements of the JSON array in order to display a table in which the user get back data about name, address and phone number of other people):

function validateTelefono() {
    setTimeout(function () {

```
   var data = JSON.parse(data);

   $.getJSON("I wrote the patthern of the JSON file 
              here", 
   function(){
      for (var i=0;  i < data.length; i++){
        $("#tbody").append("<tr>");
        $("#tbody").append("<td>" + data.nome[i] + "</td>");
        $("#tbody").append("<td>" + data.indirizzo[i] + "</td>");
        $("#tbody").append("<td>" + data.telefono[i] + "</td>");
        $("#tbody").append("</tr>");                        
                }
            );
```

For the sake of completeness, this is the whole code instead:

```
function validateTelefono() {


    console.log("function validateTelefono has been activated");
    if ($("#inlineFormInputTelefono").val() == "") {
        $("#errorLogTelefono").show();
    } else {
        $("#errorLogTelefono").hide();

        $("#cercaTelefono").prop("disabled", true);

        $("#tbody").empty();


        setTimeout(function () {

               var data = JSON.parse(data);

            $.getJSON(
                "D:\Unknown\array.json",

                //success
                function(){
                    console.log(data);

                    for (var i=0;    i < data.length; i++){       
                        $("#tbody").append("<tr>");
                        $("#tbody").append("<td>" + data.nome[i] + "</td>");
                        $("#tbody").append("<td>" + data.indirizzo[i] + "</td>");
                        $("#tbody").append("<td>" + data.telefono[i] + "</td>");
                        $("#tbody").append("</tr>");
                    }
                }
            );

            $("#tabella").show();

            $("#cercaTelefono").prop("disabled", false);
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

While opening the page in the browser I get a:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
>       at JSON.parse ()

It's referred to the following line of code:

```
            var data = JSON.parse(data);
```

I suppose the error is the *data* inside the parenthesis.

What I should write **instead of "data"**? Or is there any other reason why the Jquery method doesn't work?

- - - - - **PROBLEM SOLVED** - - - - - - >

1) I deleted the following line of code and the error message above disappeared (thank you for the suggestion):

```
var data = JSON.parse(data);
```

I got this other error instead after I did it:

[image]

This was caused by the syntax of the url in the `url` parameter of the `getJSON` method: the whole path (*"D:\Unknown\array.json"*) wasn't recognized for it doesn't live "inside" the folder where my javascript file is located ("Unknown"); instead, it's referring to an external folder ("D").
 in other terms, I edited the url this way:

```
"array.json"
```

"*array.jason*" is located in the same folder of the javascript file ("Unknown") which it's been used by. So the correct syntax of the whole snippet is the following:

```
$.getJSON(

                "array.json",

                function(data){

                    for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++){                        

                        $("#tbody").append("<tr>");
                        $("#tbody").append("<td>" + data[i].nome + "</td>");
                        $("#tbody").append("<td>" + data[i].indirizzo + "</td>");
                        $("#tbody").append("<td>" + data[i].telefono + "</td>");
                        $("#tbody").append("</tr>");
                    }
                }
            );
```

Comment: Comment out the line `var data = JSON.parse(data);` - it does nothing.

Comment: thank you @skobaljic. I did it, now I don't get that error, but how am I supposed to refer to my json file instead?

Comment: You might be getting an error when you request the json file (u is the first letter of `undefined`).

Answer (score 1):

No need to parse as JSON because it already is in JSON format. But don't forget that the request returns an array, so (mind the data.key[i] change to data[i].key):

```
 $.getJSON("URL-TO-JSON", 
       function(data){
          for (var i=0;  i < data.length; i++){
            $("#tbody").append("<tr>");
            $("#tbody").append("<td>" + data[i].nome + "</td>");
            $("#tbody").append("<td>" + data[i].indirizzo + "</td>");
            $("#tbody").append("<td>" + data[i].telefono + "</td>");
            $("#tbody").append("</tr>");                        
          }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse ()` is caused by the path to the json file. You have to write it as `\\` because `\` will initiate an escape sequence. So you are currently trying to escape the `U` in `Unknown`.